# JaxRsSecurityConfig conflict with quarkus-spring-data-rest and quarkus-resteasy-reactive

Tags: resteasy, spring-data-rest, quarkus

I want to use `quarkus-resteasy-reactive` to take advantage of the new error handling with `@ServerExceptionMapper`, but I also want to use `quarkus-spring-data-rest` to use the `@RepositoryRestResource` annotation.

The problem is that `quarkus-spring-data-rest` comes packages with `quarkus-resteasy`, which conflicts with `quarkus-resteasy-reactive` because they [both have JaxRsSecurityConfig.denyJaxRs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwDqG.png), resulting in the following error:

```
Multiple matching properties for name "security.jaxrs.deny-unannotated-endpoints" property was 
matched by both public boolean io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.JaxRsSecurityConfig.denyJaxRs and 
public boolean io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.common.runtime.JaxRsSecurityConfig.denyJaxRs. This is 
likely because you have an incompatible combination of extensions that both define the same 
properties (e.g. including both reactive and blocking database extensions)
```

Has anyone been able to use both of these libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from version `2.3`, `quarkus-spring-data-rest` will be based on RESTEasy Reactive.
Until then, the 2 extensions cannot be used together.

**UPDATE**

The change has actually been reverted as it caused other problems. We'll look into reinstating it for 2.4

Comment: Are you sure it's version 2.3? I'm using quarkus-spring-data-rest:2.2.3.Final and it's not based on RESTEasy Reactive.

Comment: That's what my answer says :)

Comment: Lol for some reason I read 2.2.3, I'm going crazy.